# How to customize the columns on jqGrid ColumnChooser?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

My grid has some columns that has hidden property of True (in the red border).

I'm finding the way that prevents these columns are shown on columnChooser dialog. 
[image]

We can see in the screenshot above. I don't want to show the columns (Amount, Tax) that is set to `invisible` (`hidden = true`) when grid is initialed. Is there any way to do that ?

Note that the plugin is `column chooser jqgrid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `hidedlg: true` property in the columns which you want to hide in `columnChooser` (the columns `amount` and `tax` in your example)

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `hidden:true` in `colModel` of jqGrid then columnChooser will place those column in the **Make All Visible Section**.

So to bypass that , you need to set  `hidedlg : true` in `colModel` alongside `hidden:true`.

See the [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acolmodel_options).